# AngularJS Controller as syntax and Directives

Tags: angularjs, typescript

So I have been exploring the `Controller as` syntax in AngularJS, and I want to know how to deal with `directives` and $scope, specifically inheritance of the controllers $scope or properties from a child directive.

I am using Typescript, so given this controller:

```
export class DefaultController implements IDefaultController {
    customer: Models.ICustomer;

    static $inject = ['$scope', 'config', 'customerDataService'];

    constructor(private $scope: ng.IScope, private config: ApplicationConfig, private customerDataService: Services.ICustomerDataService) {

    }

    getCustomerById(id: number): void {
        console.log(this.config.version);
        this.customerDataService.getCustomer(id).then((customer) => {
            this.customer = angular.extend(new Models.Customer(), customer);

        });
    }
}
```

How would I go about passing the customer down to a directive which would typically inherit the $scope of the parent controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case we would declare `as` like this `(inside of a View)`:

```
<div ng-controller="DefaultController as Events">
 ...
```

Almost the same for Directive def:

```
export class MyDefaultDirective implements ng.IDirective
{
    public restrict: string = "E";
    public replace: boolean = true;
    ...
    public controller: string = "DefaultController as Events";
    ...
```

We can expect, that the instance of `this` *controller* will be injected into `$scope` like this:

```
// this was done by angular
// - the 'as' part was used for a property name
// - current controller instance was injected 
var controller = this.$scope.Events;
```

So we can now access any public stuff  of our *controller*. A bit simplified (but exact) version of the above controller snippet:

```
export class DefaultController implements IDefaultController {
    // explicit public just to show that this will be available
    public customer: Models.ICustomer;
    ....

    getCustomerById(id: number): void {
        this.customerDataService.getCustomer(id).then((customer) => {

            // HERE
            // this.$scope.Events.customer is ready for use
            this.customer = angular.extend(new Models.Customer(), customer);
      ...
```

In our View *(once loaded via $http)* we can consume above result like this:

```
<div>
  {{Events.customer}} // public propeties of this.$scope
```